# Power supply rating for replacement

Tags: power

I have an audio mixing desk that I need a power supply for.

The output required is 16.8VAC 1.4 amperes. The original is discontinued but I have found one for sale that is rated 17VAC 1.2 amperes and one that is 18 VAC 2.0 amperes. Is the lower current rating a problem with the first and is the extra voltage a problem with the second?

Comment: We can't possibly know what is good or bad for your device because we don't even know what device it is. You have not said anything about the device, linked to it's user manual or service schematics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it's a Phonic MR1843X Audio Mixer. I do have a detailed schematic for it but it's nothing I understand.